# pygame forgot what a image is

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to draw a little image onto the window.
problem is, when I run the code, this pops up.

```
    AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'image'
    
    anyway here the code.
    
    import pygame, sys, os, math

    pygame.init()
    runing_left = False
    runing_right = False
    screen_Width_heigth = (1920, 1020)

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_Width_heigth))
    player_sur = screen.image.load('asset/Josh.png').convert()
    player = player_sur.get_rect(center = (17, 22))
    pygame.display.set_caption('platformer: torch guy')
    game_state = [True]
    and a bunch of code that isn't gotta help you to help me
```

Comment: Pygame did not forget what an image is. Screen simply doesn't have an attribute called image. Going through the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/) might help. If your confident that your code is correct, try updating pygame.

Comment: that a metaphor for the fact I don't know how to fix it

Comment: You probably should have said so.. That "metaphor" is extremely unclear.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer you have to use [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think that should be `pygame.image.load` instead of `screen.image.load`.

[Pygame Image reference](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html).